# How can I set a text as a shadow for a heading element?

Tags: html, css

I want a centered heading like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWeCP.png) using CSS only [Without flexbox].
[EDIT] My example using flexbox below. There are some limitations with this code as I can't use the same class again for a different heading as the title is hardcoded in the CSS. Does using flexbox for such a small task is a good practice?

```css
body {
  background-color: #0f1932;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.heading {
  color: white;
}
.heading::before {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0.06;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "demo-shadow";
}
.heading::after {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -40px;
  content: "demo";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <header>
            <div class="heading-container">
               <h1 class="heading"></h1>
            </div>
          </header>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. I have to use the custom data attribute to display dynamic content.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0f1932;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.heading {
  color: white;
}
.heading::before {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0.06;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: attr(before-title);;
}
.heading::after {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -40px;
  content: attr(after-title);;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <header>
            <div class="heading-container">
               <h1 class="heading" after-title="titele1" before-title="titele1"></h1>
               <h1 class="heading" after-title="titele2" before-title="titele2"></h1>
            </div>
          </header>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```